# Responsiveness of divs inside another div which is inside a grid

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, responsive-design

I am trying to work on full responsiveness of multiple divs inside parent div, and there are multiple parent divs of a similar kind inside a grid view with a class=" col-md-6". I tried reducing the image width and font size but nothing happens perfectly. I want it to auto adjust the elements when we reduce the screen size, keeping the values completely visible. I have shared the code and the issues in screenshots below.

**CSS**

```
.games-table{
    padding: 30px;
}

.gameRow{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.gameRow:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px;

}
.gameNo{

    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.gameNo, .imgBox, .courtBox{
    text-align: center;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.imgteam1, .imgteam2{
    width: 48px;
    height:auto;
}
.gamenum-box{
    background-color: #000066;
    color: #ffffff;

}
.gamenum-box, .imgBox, .courtBox{
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
.datetimeBox{
    padding: 5px 5px;
}
.vs-span{
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
th,td{
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
th{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.datetimeBox{
    color: #000000;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top, #cccccc, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) ) 1 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(80deg, #f1f1f1 , white, #f1f1f1);
    transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
}
table{
    transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
    width: 100%;
}

#games{
    z-index:0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}
.newDiv{
    width:50%;

}
.gamenum-box, .courtBox {
    width: 20%;
}
.datetimeBox{
    width:30%;
}
.imgBox{
    width:30%;
}
.gameVis{
    display: none;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
    .games-table{
        padding:10px;
    }
    .newDiv{
        width:100%;

    }

    .imgteam1, .imgteam2{
        width: 27px;
    }
    .gamenum-box, .imgBox, .courtBox{
        padding: 16px 1px;
    }
    th,td{
        padding: 0px 1px;
    }

}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
    .games-table{
        padding: 5px;
    }
    /* .gameNoVis{
        display: none;
    }
    .gameVis{
        display: block;
    } */
    .gamenum-box{
        width: 13%;
    }
    .imgBox{
        width: 32%;
    }
    .datetimeBox{
        width: 40%;
    }
    .courtBox {
        width: 15%;
    }
}
```

**HTML CODE**

```
<div class="game-table">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="head mb-4">
                    <h2>Matches</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">  
            <!-- Start Games Section -->
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
                        <div id="games">
                        <div class="row gameRow">
                            <div class="gamenum-box col-md-2">
                                <p class="gameNo">GAME</p>
                                <p class="gameNo">1</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="imgBox col-md-4">
                                <img src="../assets/images/games/team1.png" class="imgteam1">
                                <span class="vs-span">VS</span>
                                <img src="../assets/images/games/team2.png" class="imgteam2">
                            </div>
                            <div class="datetimeBox col-md-4">
                                <table>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th><b>Date</b></th>
                                        <th><b>Time</b></th>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><b>12 Jan 2019</b></td>
                                        <td><b>12:00PM</b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                </table>                                 
                            </div> 
                            <div class="courtBox col-md-2">
                                <p class="gameNo">COURT</p>
                                <p class="gameNo">1</p>
                            </div>                
                        </div>
                        </div>                       
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
             <div id="games">
             <div class="row gameRow">
        <div class="gamenum-box col-md-2">
            <p class="gameNo">GAME</p>
            <p class="gameNo">1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="imgBox col-md-4">
            <img src="../assets/images/games/team1.png" class="imgteam1">
            <span class="vs-span">VS</span>
            <img src="../assets/images/games/team2.png" class="imgteam2">
        </div>
        <div class="datetimeBox col-md-4">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><b>Date</b></th>
                    <th><b>Time</b></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>12 Jan 2019</b></td>
                    <td><b>12:00PM</b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>                                 
        </div> 
        <div class="courtBox col-md-2">
            <p class="gameNo">COURT</p>
            <p class="gameNo">1</p>
        </div>                
    </div>
    </div>                       
</div>
            <!-- End Games Section -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Screenshots**

[Full Width on laptop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEhsS.png)

[1140x570 pixels view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E6kNa.png)

[iphone6,7,8 view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SkfQl.png)

[ipadpro view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PO3rz.png)

**Actual Image used**

[Team 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjbQJ.png)

[Team 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJdIz.png)

Comment: I was checking your code inside Code Snippet, but it doesn't work well when you have to check for responsiveness on various screens.  I checked your codes on my own environment, your web page looks pretty good.  The only evaluation I cannot make is that you have not your original images.  I suspect your images are the problem, otherwise the grids work just fine as to responsiveness.

Comment: Can you add a code snippet with your images, so we can work on adjustment if there are any problems?  or I don't know... share your images.

Comment: @Mugé I have shared the images in the question post! Please check... And as for the code snippet, this is from a component of angular 8 code.

Comment: so is it working for you?

Comment: Yes. Thank you! I also created a responsive design without box height and it works very well!

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vast, but I will try to explain like a birds-eye concept on how you can approach your project.

So obviously you are using bootstrap, which is pretty perfect styling for various screens.

Your coding style needs some refining, they are a little all over the place.  When you line up the divs, you start with the larger grid.

Example:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
```

has to be

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12>   // hierarchically
```

First clean that part up.

Second, you need to continue thinking in terms of grids.  Inside a grid, you divide again into grids, as if it is a full page, so the grids all nicely complement and line up with each other, as it is with your parent grids  (in a perfect world!).

The shortfalls of the grid is when you have more text in one box, compared to the second box, one will be longer than the the next box.  So the amount of text will influence your grid's height, unless you give those boxes a height or all your text has as many characters as your other box.  When you give a height, for a large screen, you need to adjust those heights - through @media.
This is just to simplify the concept of 'responsive websites'.

CSS

```
.my-fixed-height-box-01 {
    height: 3em;     // adapt to your design
    }

@media only screen and (max-width:600px) {
    .my-fixed-height-box-01 {
    height: 4em;     // adapt to your design
    }
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    .my-fixed-height-box-01 {
    height: 6em;     // adapt to your design
    }
}
```

Bootstrap has design elements for images that will turn images responsive as well.

Try to keep your codes organized and clean, that you can build on and around them easier.  When you run into a specific problem during this process, Stackoverflow is a great place to come back to.

Comment: Using classes hierarchically  from large to small is not an issue because Bootstrap is "mobile first".

Comment: @bron it is not about the screen, it is about keeping your code clean.  Make a habit of organizing.

Comment: Organizing the code in a template is good practice but the Boostrap css is mobile first, so I think the best approach is that the template also is coded mobile first. BS documentation and examples use this approach also.

Comment: @Mugé Did you check the images bro?

Comment: @Mugé .my-fixed-height-box-01 is the height of which container?

Comment: @Bijay I was giving this example hypothetically.  But hold on pls.  I have gathered the design for you.  Will post shortly.

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was an hypothetical overall conceptualization of how to go about the grids.

As to my solution, I would not have designed it with tables, because tables can create design limitations as to growing the design.  However, if you have to, then it is fine to use tables.

Again, I would have gone a different route if I had to re-code again.

I added some @media solutions.

Also to definitely keep in mind, when you use responsive design and you want to align your images inside grids, make sure they all are same size.  Even a 1px difference can give you a headache.

In my example, I have adjusted image sizes to 200px height and width each.  Even if it looks OK on your screen, there are differences when images get larger and even now, one looks smaller than the other if you leave it like that.

More importantly, I changed your image from .png to .jpg.  Unless you need a transparent background in an image, you can use .png, otherwise use .jpg because it is a smaller file and healthier for your page load.  Also, if you are going to use your images like thumbnails, 200px is too large, reduce them to 60px or something, dependent on your screen size.

```css
.games-table{
    padding: 30px;
}

.gameRow{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px 0px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.gameRow:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px 0px;

}
.gameNo{

    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.gameNo, .imgBox, .courtBox{
    text-align: center;
}

li{
    list-style-type: none;
}
.imgteam1, .imgteam2{
    width: 48px;
    height:auto;
}
.gamenum-box{
    background-color: #000066;
    color: #ffffff;

}
.gamenum-box, .imgBox, .courtBox{
    padding: 20px 20px;
}
.datetimeBox{
    padding: 5px 5px;
}
.vs-span{
    margin: 0px 10px;
}
th,td{
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
th{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #cccccc;
}
.datetimeBox{
    color: #000000;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-image: linear-gradient(to top, #cccccc, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) ) 1 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(80deg, #f1f1f1 , white, #f1f1f1);
    transform: skew(-10deg, 0deg);
}
table{
    transform: skew(10deg, 0deg);
    width: 100%;
}

#games{
    z-index:0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ( 0 );
    transform: translateZ( 0 );
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 0.6s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    backface-visibility: hidden;

}
.newDiv{
    width:50%;

}
.gamenum-box, .courtBox {
    width: 20%;
}
.datetimeBox{
    width:30%;
}
.imgBox{
    width:30%;
}
.gameVis{
    display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 766px) {
.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4, .col-5, .col-6, .col-7, .col-8, .col-9, .col-10, .col-11, .col-12, .col, .col-sm-1, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-3, .col-sm-4, .col-sm-5, .col-sm-6, .col-sm-7, .col-sm-8, .col-sm-9, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-11, .col-sm-12, .col-sm, .col-md-1, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, .col-md-4, .col-md-5, .col-md-6, .col-md-7, .col-md-8, .col-md-9, .col-md-10, .col-md-11, .col-md-12, .col-md, .col-lg-1, .col-lg-2, .col-lg-3, .col-lg-4, .col-lg-5, .col-lg-6, .col-lg-7, .col-lg-8, .col-lg-9, .col-lg-10, .col-lg-11, .col-lg-12, .col-lg, .col-xl-1, .col-xl-2, .col-xl-3, .col-xl-4, .col-xl-5, .col-xl-6, .col-xl-7, .col-xl-8, .col-xl-9, .col-xl-10, .col-xl-11, .col-xl-12, .col-xl {
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
}

  .container {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }

  .imgbox {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }

  .imgteam1, .imgteam2{
        width: 30.3333% !important;
    }

    .imgbox {
        width: 100%;
    }

     th,td{
        padding: 0px 1px;
    }
    p, ul, blockquote, pre, td, th, label {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 601px) {
  .container {
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
  }

  .imgbox {
    padding-right: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
  }

  .imgteam1, .imgteam2{
        width: 33.3333%;
    }

    .imgbox {
        width: 100%;
    }

     th,td{
        padding: 0px 1px;
    }
    p, ul, blockquote, pre, td, th, label { /* This part I extended to other style designs as well */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-width:600px){
    
    .games-table{
        padding:10px;
    }
    .newDiv{
        width:100%;

    }

    .imgteam1, .imgteam2{
        width: 27px;
    }
    .gamenum-box, .imgBox, .courtBox{
        padding: 16px 1px;
    }
    th,td{
        padding: 0px 1px;
    }
    p, ul, blockquote, pre, td, th, label {  /* This part I extended to other style designs as well */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    }
}
@media only screen and (max-width:480px){
 
    .games-table{
        padding: 5px;
    }
    /* .gameNoVis{
        display: none;
    }
    .gameVis{
        display: block;
    } */
    .gamenum-box{
        width: 13%;
    }
    .imgBox{
        width: 32%;
    }
    .datetimeBox{
        width: 40%;
    }
    .courtBox {
        width: 15%;
    }
    p, ul, blockquote, pre, td, th, label {  /* This part I extended to other style designs as well */
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 80%;
    line-height: 1.5em;
    margin-bottom: 1.5em;
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<!-- Stylesheets -->    
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="game_team.css" />
</head>


<div class="game-table">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">  
            <div class="col-12">
                <div class="head mb-4">
                    <h2>Matches</h2>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="row">  
            <!-- Start Games Section 1 -->
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12  col-xs-12">
             <div id="games">
             <div class="row gameRow">
        <div class="gamenum-box col-md-2">
            <p class="gameNo">GAME</p>
            <p class="gameNo">1</p>
        </div>
        <div class="imgBox col-md-4">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjbQJ.png" class="imgteam1">
            <span class="vs-span">VS</span>
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJdIz.png" class="imgteam2">
        </div>
        <div class="datetimeBox col-md-4">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><b>Date</b></th>
                    <th><b>Time</b></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>12 Jan 2019</b></td>
                    <td><b>12:00PM</b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>                                 
        </div> 
        <div class="courtBox col-md-2">
            <p class="gameNo">COURT</p>
            <p class="gameNo">1</p>
        </div>                
    </div>
    </div>                       
</div>
            <!-- End Games Section 1 -->

            <!-- Start Games Section 2 -->
            <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12  col-xs-12">
             <div id="games">
             <div class="row gameRow">
        <div class="gamenum-box col-md-2">
            <p class="gameNo">GAME</p>
            <p class="gameNo">2</p>
        </div>
        <div class="imgBox col-md-4">
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjbQJ.png" class="imgteam1">
            <span class="vs-span">VS</span>
            <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJdIz.png" class="imgteam2">
        </div>
        <div class="datetimeBox col-md-4">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th><b>Date</b></th>
                    <th><b>Time</b></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><b>12 Jan 2019</b></td>
                    <td><b>12:00PM</b></td>
                </tr>
            </table>                                 
        </div> 
        <div class="courtBox col-md-2">
            <p class="gamebox">COURT</p>
            <p class="gameNo">2</p>
        </div>                
    </div>
    </div>                       
</div>
            <!-- End Games Section 2 -->

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```